# Firebase: Query collection children from a list of keys (Swift 4)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I retrieve a collection of data using a list of key IDs.

Much similar to SQL statements using WHERE...IN() clause:
for example:

```
 SELECT * FROM collection WHERE key IN(key1, key2, key3,...)
```

We can easily retrieve one item at a time but it's obviously not efficient:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("key")
let data1 = ref.child(key1)
let data2 = ref.child(key2)
let data3 = ref.child(key3)
```

Thanks in advance,

Yohann

Comment: Firebase [RealtimeDB](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write) doesn't support complex queries, Try [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) instead, if you are in initial stage.

Comment: are those keys random-uuids?, if not then you can queryOrder by key, and further filter by using queryStartingAtValue and queryEndingAtValue to bound the return values.

Comment: yes, the keys are random, they can be anywhere within the parent node